# rexexp_replace doesn't work as expected

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to replace the below text to fill the question mark

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('?????/ ??????  John
??? ????? ??????? ?? ????? Pediatric Clinic ?? ??? 10 MAY 15 ?????? 01:15 PM
 ?????? ?????? ??? 15 ????? ?? ?????? ??????
Thanks.',
 '^[?/ ]+([a-z0-9 ]+)[?\s]+([a-z0-9 ]+)[?\s]+([0-9a-z ]+)[?\s]+([0-9a-z: ]+).+$','Mr/Ms \1, We would like to remind you about your appointment in \2 on \3 at \4. Please come 15 minutes before your appointment time. Thanks ',1,1, 'm') msg
FROM DUAL
```

But I alway get the same correpted string, even though the match is working fine:

```
SELECT 'Ok' Result FROM DUAL WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('?????/ ??????  John
??? ????? ??????? ?? ????? Pediatric Clinic ?? ??? 10 MAY 15 ?????? 01:15 PM
 ?????? ?????? ??? 15 ????? ?? ?????? ??????
Thanks.',
'^[?/ ]+([a-z0-9 ]+)[?\s]+([a-z0-9 ]+)[?\s]+([0-9a-z ]+)[?\s]+([0-9a-z: ]+).+$', 'm')
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Please add the actual output you're getting plus the output you're expecting to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('?????/ ??????  John
??? ????? ??????? ?? ????? Pediatric Clinic ?? ??? 10 MAY 15 ?????? 01:15 PM
 ?????? ?????? ??? 15 ????? ?? ?????? ??????
Thanks.',
 '[?/ ]*([^?[:cntrl:] ]*)[[:cntrl:]?/ ]*([^?]*) [?/ ]*([^?]*) [?/ ]*([^?[:cntrl:]]*)[[:cntrl:]?/ ]*([^? ]*)[?/ ]*([^? ]*)(.*)'
 ,'Mr/Ms \1, We would like to remind you about your appointment in \2 on \3 at \4. Please come 15 minutes before your appointment time. Thanks',1,1, 'm') msg
FROM DUAL;
```

Your regex pattern is matching to your second line ("??? ????? ??????? ?? ????? Pediatric Clinic ?? ??? 10 MAY 15 ?????? 01:15 PM") and is replacing just your second line with the replacement expression.

Comment: Thanks it is working but I am wondering why it includes the new line with the name.

Comment: @masker: I edited my answer to remove the new line characters.